# Stationarity in a time series implying that the correlation between consecutive terms must be constant?

Tags: time-series, econometrics

[image]

I'm reading this definition (from Chapter 11 of an introductory econometrics textbook from Wooldrige) as the following: each consecutive pair of terms (let's let m = 2) are assumed to have the same joint probability distribution and therefore must have the same correlation (as correlation is determined by the joint distribution - although I am a bit rusty from pure probability theory).

However, the textbook posits otherwise (see image).

Comment: An *implication* of a definition is not the same as the definition itself.  The definition makes no mention of consecutive pairs: it concerns *all* pairs (and triples, etc.).

Comment: I just misread the my image (I thought it says "stationarity *doesn't* require  that the nature of any correlation is the same across all time periods).